# Fill my List at view.xml with values from js array

Tags: sapui5

I want to fill my List at the `view.xml` with the values of an Object which includes an array (arr). I get the object before from a SAP software via a web service.

`Test.view.xml`:

```
<HBox>
                            
   <List id="select_menu" visible="hidde" mode="SingleSelectMaster" selectionChange="onDetail">
         <StandardListItem title="{Id}" />
   </List>
</HBox>
```

`test.controller.js`:

```
        onTest: function(){
            var itemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                title : "{Id}",             
                icon: "icons/yellow_sign_micro.png",                
                iconInset: false,               
                customData: [               
                new sap.ui.core.CustomData({                
                key: "flag",                
                value: "false"              
                })]
                });
            this.getView().byId("select_menu").bindAggregation("items", {
                path: arr,
                template: itemTemplat               
                })
        }
    });
```

Comment: _> from SAP via a web service..._ --> Which product from do you mean by "SAP"? SAP is a company and not a product. And what kind of "service" is the web service? Do you mean an OData service? If so, which OData version? Please add more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
myModel.setData(yourResponseFromWebservice);
```

There is no need for creating controls with JS. You can use XML for binding.
Write your data in a [JSON Model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel) and bind your model with your list via `items`

---

```
 <List items="{myModel>/items}" id="select_menu" visible="hidden" mode="SingleSelectMaster" selectionChange="onDetail">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem icon="icons/yellow_sign_micro.png" title="{myModel>Id}" >
        <customData>
          <core:CustomData key="flag" value="false" writeToDom="true" />
       </customData>
       </StandardListItem>
    </items>
 </List>
```